# Is there a way to check if a database exists in Mongo from the Node.js driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I'm finding it surprisingly difficult to see find a way to see if a database exists or not in MongoDB from the Node.js driver. There *seems* to be no method in the Node.js driver to check if a database exists.

For example, the following doesn't throw an error:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

mongo.connect({ 'mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseThatDoesntExists }, function (err, db) {
   // There is no error
   if (err) console.log(err);
   // Let's get some stats on a database that doesn't exist
   db.statsAsync(function (err, result) {
      console.log(result);
   });
});
```

Results will be an object like this:

```
{ db: 'databaseThatDoesntExist',
  collections: 0,
  objects: 0,
  avgObjSize: 0,
  dataSize: 0,
  storageSize: 0,
  numExtents: 0,
  indexes: 0,
  indexSize: 0,
  fileSize: 0,
  ok: 1 }
```

Can you check to see if a database exists in MongoDB form the Node.js driver?  Is there even a concept of a database existing in MongoDB? Is referencing a database that doesn't exist just referencing a database with no collections?

Mongo, why can't you just throw an error! I like when my code `throws` errors!

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049722/check-if-mongodb-database-exists ?

Comment: better this with the Node.js driver http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571021/how-to-list-all-mongodb-databases-in-node-js

Comment: how to stop automatic database creation while access any collection ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if [`db.admin().listDatabases`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/admin.html#listdatabases) contains the database name.

If the server has [authorization](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authorization/) enabled, you will need the appropriate [permissions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication-without-bypass/).

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to tell whether a database exists would be from the mongo she'll. To list all databases available, enter the following into your Mongo shell.

```
show dbs
```

To list the database you're currently using, enter:

```
db
```

To explicitly select a database, enter:

```
use <database>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did want to do it from the Node.js driver. I updated my question to reflect that.